# How can a 2D Manim transformation be embedded in 3D space?

Tags: animation, math, geometry, mathematical-expressions, manim

Suppose I have a Manim transformation animation in ℝ<sup>2</sup>, such as

```
from manimlib.imports import *

def function(point):
    x, y, z = point
    return (x + 3*y)*RIGHT + (2*x + 4*y)*UP

class Transient(LinearTransformationScene):
    CONFIG = {
        "show_basis_vectors" : True,
    }
    def construct(self):
        self.wait(7)
        self.apply_nonlinear_transformation(function)
        self.wait(29)
```

How can I embed this transformation into a plane in ℝ<sup>3</sup> instead?  It would look like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yzV8m8X3Kk), only it would be a transformation rather than a vector field.

I can't seem to find the Multivariable Calculus code in the old_projects directory (the MV course *was* made with Manim, right?), so I can't study the code for the vector field to emulate it.  Similarly, a lot of code from the 3D transformation Linear Algebra chapter seems to be missing, and the chapter doesn't contain this exact type of transformation in any case, so it's not clear that it would help.

Comment: That animation was not made in Manim, but in Grapher, an exclusive MacOS application.

Comment: I don't think manim is interactive.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Hmm, interactivity wouldn't be essential, so long as the camera rotates as it does here (https://youtu.be/rHLEWRxRGiM?t=217).  Would it be possible, for example, to embed one 2D transformation in the plane z = -1 and another in the plane z = 1, and have them play together?

Comment: @TheoremOfBeethoven ^^